# Image Tag OnMouseOver Not Fired

Tags: javascript

I have very simple code and I am not sure why the Foo function is not fired when the mouse is over the image:

```
here <img id="sss" alt="some image" onmouseover="Foo(this);" src="https://www.google.com/intl/en_com/images/srpr/logo3w.png" width="16" height="16"   />

<div onmouseover="Foo(this);"> 
    THIS IS DIV
</div>

function Foo(obj) 
{
    alert('s');
}
```

**UPDATE 1:**

What actually happens is that I create the image element dynamically and then add it to the page. The Foo function is already inside the JS file but it never gets called.

Comment: It doesn't matter how you add the image - what you have is fine.  The problem is that Foo is not available for some reason.  Try just adding a plain button to your page and setting its onclick to `Foo(this)` and see if it fires

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you have currently is correct, as [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uXAQ4/) shows.  I'm guessing your problem is that Foo is not global on your page.

---

Also, instead of passing `this` as a parameter to your function, you can set it as the this value *inside of* your function by using `call`

```
onmouseover="Foo.call(this);"

function Foo()  {
    alert(this.src); //this is the img you just mouse-overed 
}
```

---

Finally, consider changing `Foo` to `foo`, since functions starting with capital letters usually denote constructors in JavaScript.

Comment: @azamsharp - `Foo` will still work, I was just saying that *once you fixed the problem*, you should consider renaming it to `foo`

Answer (score 1):

If that's your actual code then the only issue is that you need to wrap the JavaScript in a `<script>`:

```
<script>
function Foo(obj) {
    alert('s');
}
</script>​
```

See a demo:

- http://jsfiddle.net/NmSBs/

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: Nothing is wrong with the code as long as you have the script included in the `<head>`

try it: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZngnM/)

Comment: @azamsharp - as <ok, I'm not repeating that username> and I have both told you, your code above is correct.  Your page is not loading Foo for some reason.

Comment: Here is my JSFiddle. The JavaScript should be loaded on onLoad. http://jsfiddle.net/At2zt/

Comment: @azamsharp - you made the fiddle wrongly - you don't want MooTools on load.  This one works:  http://jsfiddle.net/At2zt/1/